# How can I input a word, read through a dictionary, and print the word's translation?

Tags: c, string, file

My objective is to input a string "sana" which will at the end print only one corresponding result. Ie: if I enter the word "sana" it would print "Word sana is in English word" and if the user enters "word" it prints "Word word is in Finnish sana". So the code is not working at all so I wanted to ask how should I continue. `if`-`else` doesn't work at all but I thought it would help me visualize where to go there.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/*
Read file line by line
split lines using ; as delimiter
store first/second part in some array
ask user to input and search the word in that array
*/

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char sana[30];
    char *p;
    void *tmp;
    int lasku = 0;
    int pal = 1;
    int i;
    char **vars = NULL;
    char **vals = NULL;

    fp = fopen("dictionary.txt", "r");

    printf("Word: ");
    scanf("%s", sana);

    while (fgets(sana, sizeof(sana), fp)) {
        sana[strcspn(sana, "\n")] = 0;
        if (!(p = strchr(sana, ';')))
            continue;
        *p++ = 0;       //poistaa ;

        if (!strlen(sana) || !strlen(p))
            continue;

        if (!(tmp = realloc(vars, (lasku + 1) * sizeof(char*))))
            goto out;
        vars = (char**)tmp;

        if (!(tmp = realloc(vals, (lasku + 1) * sizeof(char*))))
            goto out;
        vals = (char**)tmp;

        vars[lasku] = strdup(sana);
        vals[lasku] = strdup(p);
        lasku++;

        if (!vars[lasku-1] || ! vals[lasku-1])
            goto out;
    }

    pal = 0;

    if (i == 0 || i == 2 || i == 4)
        printf("Word %s is in English %s\n", vars[i], vals[i]);
    else
    if (i == 1 || i == 3 || i == 5)
        printf("Word %s is in Finnish %s\n", vals[i], vars[i]);
    else
        printf("Word can't be found in the dictionary");

  out:
    fclose(fp);

    if (vars)
        for (i = 0; i < lasku; i++)
            free(vars[i]);
    if (vals)
        for (i = 0; i < lasku; i++)
            free(vals[i]);
    free(vars);
    free(vals);

    return pal;
}
```

Comment: "not working" is never a good problem description. Give the exact input, expected behaviour vs actual behaviour. Even more importantly, learning effective debugging is the next step you should take. Run your program in a debugger and step thru it line by line examining the flow and variable values as it runs. More tips here: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: I am really not sure what you are trying to accomplish. But you are reading a string from `stdin` into the buffer `sana`, and on the the next line you overwrite the buffer with a line from `fp`. Whatever you are trying to do, am quite sure that is a bug.

Comment: `if(i==0 || i==2 || i==4)` What is that supposed to be checking for? Considering `i` is never set before that point.

Comment: Not sure exactly what your asking about as you have not clearly stated that. But if you want to check for `"sana"` and `"word"` then you should have `strcmp` calls somewhere. Like `if (strcmp(sana, "sana")==0) printf("Word sana is in English word");`

Comment: @kaylum scanf("%s", sana); is supposed to be the word that the user wants to translate into another language in the file. I didn't know how to continue from that but I wanted it to translate "word" into another language's "word".

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Because `scanf` writes into the `sana` variable which is then immediately overwritten by the `fgets` call which writes to the same `sana` variable. So for starters you need two variables - one for user input and one for reading from file. And what is the format of the file? That matters as parsing that is a major step in any solution.

Comment: @kaylum I was able to print all the translations with for loop but my goal was to just print one result, the one user is inputting.

Comment: Yes, but what is the format of the translation file? For example does it have an English word followed by a Finnish word on each line? That info is needed to be able to advise you on how to use it to compare against the user input.

Comment: Please do not write things like `*p++ = 0;` to show off your cleverness, leave that to the OCCC. Nobody wants to dig through the c standard to find out if it means `*(p++) = 0;` or `(*p)++ = 0;` Split that line into two lines to make your intentions clear. There are no reasons to be terse.

Comment: @kaylum the content inside the file is like this:
sana;word
kirja;book
luku;chapter

Comment: @HAL9000 noted, I'll apologize and remember that in the future.

Comment: First, do you understand that you need to fix the `scanf` to not use the same `sana` variable as the `fgets`? Assuming you fixed that then the check is just `if (strcmp(vars[lasku], sana) == 0) { printf("Word %s is in Finnish %s\n", sana, vals[lasku]); } else if (strcmp(vals[lasku], sana) == 0) { printf("Word %s is in English %s\n", sana, vars[lasku]); }`

Comment: @houhouhou, no need to apologize, some comments seem harsh. That is because they are often kept short and to the point, not because we are offended by you programming

Comment: Do you really have to build a dictionary in memory? Why not just process the dictionary entry in `dictionary.txt` as you are reading it?

Comment: @kaylum

    if (strcmp(temp, "sana")==0 || strcmp(temp, "kirja")==0 || strcmp(temp, "luku")==0)
        printf("Sana %s on englanniksi %s\n", vars[i], vals[i]);

    else if(strcmp(temp, "word")==0)
        printf("Sana %s on suomeksi %s\n", vals[i], vars[i]);

It kind of worked for me with this but only for sana and word but for kirja and luku it didn't. I tried your suggestion too but it didn't print anything.

Comment: @HAL9000 thanks for saying that! Although I was preparing for harsh comments since my code does look pretty messy so...

Hmm as for the dictionary.txt suggestion, I'm not sure what do you mean with it? Our task was to use this given file that had these words written inside it.

Comment: The point I am trying to make about processing the entries as you are reading `dictionary.txt`, is that you don't need to build the arrays pointed to by `vars` and `vals`. Just read a line from the file, split it into an english and finnish word, compare them with the input and do something if there is a match, then read the next line, etc...

Comment: .@HAL9000 `*p++ = 0;` is really quite idiomatic/ubiquitous. And, AFAICT, both your alternatives are the same. (i.e.) there is _no_ difference between `*(p++)` and `(*p)++`. And, they mean `*p++` which is easier to understand

Comment: @CraigEstey, Yes it is quite idiomatic, but when presented with buggy code from a beginning programmer, this is one more thing I have to consider. Does he understand the difference? Is he using it the way it is supposed to? Do *I* actually remember the correct precedence? And the fact that somebody, which I assume is an experienced programmer, forgets that there is a difference between `*(p++)` and `(*p)++` just proves my point :-)

Comment: @HAL9000 There is _no_ difference. It's postfix. See: https://godbolt.org/z/TYWj97Khj and look at the disassembly of `fnc*` What do _you_ think is the difference?

Comment: @CraigEstey, `*(p++)` increments `p` and is indeed the same as `*p++`. `(*p)++` increments whatever `p` points at. I understand you thought i wrote `*(p)++`, but I didn't, which just shows that being to terse often lets us do stupid mistakes. Both should return the same value, but the side effects differ.

Answer (score 2):

The code does not work because:

- you overwrite the word in `sana` when you read the dictionary.
- you never set `i`.
- testing the value of uninitialized variable `i` has undefined behavior.

You should first local the dictionary in memory, then read words from the user and search them in the dictionary for matches.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/*
Read file line by line
split lines using ; as delimiter
store first/second part in some array
ask user to input and search the word in that array
*/

int main() {
    FILE *fp;
    char sana[30];
    char **tmp;
    int lasku = 0, i, found, error = 0;
    char **vars = NULL;
    char **vals = NULL;

    fp = fopen("dictionary.txt", "r");

    while (fgets(sana, sizeof(sana), fp)) {
        sana[strcspn(sana, "\n")] = '\0';
        if (!(p = strchr(sana, ';')))
            continue;
        *p++ = '\0';
        if (!*sana || !*p)
            continue;

        if (!(tmp = realloc(vars, (lasku + 1) * sizeof(*vars)))) {
            error = 1;
            break;
        }
        vars = tmp;

        if (!(tmp = realloc(vals, (lasku + 1) * sizeof(*vals)))) {
            error = 1;
            break;
        }
        vals = tmp;

        vars[lasku] = strdup(sana);
        vals[lasku] = strdup(p);
        lasku++;

        if (!vars[lasku-1] || !vals[lasku-1]) {
            error = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);

    if (!error) {
        for (;;) {
            printf("Word: ");
            if (scanf("%29s", sana) != 1)
                break;
            found = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < lasku; i++) {
                if (!strcmp(sana, vars[i]) {
                    printf("Word %s is in English %s\n", vars[i], vals[i]);
                    found = 1;
                }
                if (!strcmp(sana, vals[i]) {
                    printf("Word %s is in Finnish %s\n", vals[i], vars[i]);
                    found = 1;
                }
            }
            if (!found) {
                printf("Word can't be found in the dictionary");
            }
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < lasku; i++) {
        free(vars[i]);
        free(vals[i]);
    }
    free(vars);
    free(vals);

    return error;
}
```

Comment: Nice, UV.  Yet consider `realloc(vals, (lasku + 1) * sizeof *vals)` instead of `realloc(vals, (lasku + 1) * sizeof(char*)))`.  How to know if `char*` is the right type?  Reviewer, me, needs to search up various lines (21) and eventually find `char **vals = NULL;` and see it is correct.  With `realloc(vals, (lasku + 1) * sizeof *vals)`, I know it is right just by look at that single line of code. IMHO, sizing by the refenced object rather than the type is easier to code right, review and maintain.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: I agree 100%. Answer updated. Happy new year!

Comment: Bonne année....