# Comparing between a number and array

Tags: c

I am trying to compare a number with an array containing some certain unknown values, and I want to get the number of integers which are less than the compared number.

For example:

The array would be: `-2 5 2 5 7 9 10`

Compared Number is: `8`

Answer: `5`

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

long long data[200000] = { 0 };

int cmpfunc(const void *a, const void *b) {
    return (*(long long*)b - *(long long*)a);
}

int main() {
    int numbers, i, j, z, counter, testcases;
    long long check;
    scanf("%d", &numbers);
    for (i = 0; i < numbers; i++)
        scanf("%lld", &data[i]);

    qsort(data, numbers, sizeof(long long), cmpfunc);

    scanf("%d", &testcases);
    for (j = 0; j < testcases; j++) {
        scanf("%lld", &check);
        counter = numbers;
        
        for (z = 0; z < numbers; z++) {
            if (check >= data[z])
                break;
            counter--;
        }
        printf("%d\n", counter);
    }
}
```

My program still runs slower than the requirement allows me, is there any way to make this faster?

Comment: You might take a look at *binary search*.

Comment: If you have a sorted array, then, you can use binary search which has O(logn) time complexity. But, you can search linearly without sorting the array. Because, sorting array has O(nlogn) time complexity. That's why your algorithm has O(nlogn) time complexity. But, you can accomplish your task with O(n) time complexity by searching linearly.

Comment: And why using `long long` ?

Comment: The example data set is tiny.  How big can the “real” data sets get?  Note that a standard binary search won't help; in the sample data, it would look for 8 and not find it.  You need a modified binary search that finds the position of the largest value smaller than the target value.

Answer (score 3):

There are some issues with your approach:

- the comparison function does not work correctly if the difference of the 2 numbers exceeds the range of type `int`, which is easy to achieve even with `int` values, eg: comparing `INT_MAX` and `INT_MIN`.  You should instead use this:

  ```
    int cmpfunc(const void *aa, const void *bb) {
        const long long *a = aa;
        const long long *b = bb;
        return (*a > *b) - (*a < *b);
    }
  ```
- sorting the values is not always necessary for your goal: it is only useful if the number of lookups is greater than `log2(N)` as sorting the array takes time proportional to **N.log(N)**.
- furthermore, you should take advantage of the sorting, using binary search to locate the number potential position and determine the count directly from that position. The current approach using linear search works the same with a sorted and unsorted array.
- unless it is part of the assignment, 200000 might not be enough for all test cases. Allocating the array seems a better approach.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int cmpfunc(const void *aa, const void *bb) {
    const long long *a = aa;
    const long long *b = bb;
    return (*a > *b) - (*a < *b);
}

int main() {
    int numbers, i, j, z, counter, testcases;
    long long *data;
    long long check;

    if (scanf("%d", &numbers) != 1)
        return 1;
    data = calloc(sizeof(*data), numbers);
    if (!data)
        return 1;
    for (i = 0; i < numbers; i++) {
        if (scanf("%lld", &data[i]) != 1)
            return 1;
    }
    if (scanf("%d", &testcases) != 1)
        return 1;

    if (testcases < 63 && (1ULL << testcases) < numbers) {
        for (j = 0; j < testcases; j++) {
            if (scanf("%lld", &check) != 1)
                return 1;
            counter = 0;
            
            for (z = 0; z < numbers; z++) {
                counter += (check < data[z]);
            }
            printf("%d\n", counter);
        }
    } else {
        qsort(data, numbers, sizeof(*data), cmpfunc);
        for (j = 0; j < testcases; j++) {
            if (scanf("%lld", &check) != 1)
                return 1;

            size_t a = 0, b = numbers;
            while (a < b) {
                size_t m = a + (b - a) / 2;
                if (data[m] < check)
                    a = m + 1;
                else
                    b = m;
            }
            counter = b;
            printf("%d\n", counter);
        }
    }
    free(data);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "it is only useful if the number of lookups is greater than log(N)" ==? Interesting threshold - sounds right.

Comment: Why `testcases < 31` and not, say. `testcases < 63`?

Comment: BTW, much like  a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70545651/how-can-i-input-a-word-read-through-a-dictionary-and-print-the-words-translat/70546277?noredirect=1#comment124706781_70546277) of yesterday, instead of `qsort(data, numbers, sizeof(long long), cmpfunc);`, could use `qsort(data, numbers, sizeof data[0], cmpfunc);` or the like to form the element size.  True OP did use `sizeof(long long)` and this is a secondary concern.

Answer (score 2):

**Binary vs. linear**

Rather than a linear search

```
    for (z = 0; z < numbers; z++) {
        if (check >= data[z])
            break;
        counter--;
    }
```

Use a binary one

```
    found = false;
    int lo = 0;
    int hi = numbers - 1;
    while (lo <= hi) {
      int mid = (hi-lo)/2 + lo;
      if (data[mid] < check) lo = mid + 1;
      else if (data[mid] > check) hi = mid - 1;
      else {
        found = true;
        // found it!
        // Now look for first index less than check with TBD code.
      }
    }  
         
    // Value of lo, hi  can be use to determine the count.
```

**Avoid overflow**

`*(long long*)b - *(long long*)a` may overflow.

```
int cmpfunc(const void *a, const void *b) {
  // return (*(long long*)b - *(long long*)a);
  return (*(long long*)b > *(long long*)a) - (*(long long*)b < *(long long*)a);
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid your binary lookup function will not find the lowest index in case of multiple occurrences, hence more work is needed to determine the count.

Comment: @chqrlie "multiple occurrences" covered in the `Now look for first index less than check with TBD code.` part.  I did not want to give OP _all_ the code.